# HLK-RM-04 - http response are not clear

Tags: wifi, pic, uart

1. Currently, i'm working with HLK-RM-04 wifi to UART module. I'm using this in server mode. I've connected this module(tx/rx) to my PIC16F887.  Connections are fine and I can able to transmit and receive data.
2. All i'm doing here is giving a html request from a browser/web client, and i'm expecting my data(responded from my MCU) to be displayed in browser.  But i'm not getting it properly.  Sometimes it works in right way, but most of the time if displays some junk value.
3. To analyze from MCU side, i tapped my MCUs Tx pin and connected to PC COM port.  Yes, it seems it works perfect.  I can able to see my data in hyper terminal, what i'm transmitting from MCU.
4. So to analyze from PC side, I used a free web-sniffer.  There I can see data received was junk at sometimes. (Pls refer images) I couldn't able to guess whats wrong ?
5. Data sent to wifi module from MCU was right, but data sent from wifi module as wifi frames are bad ? 
   Is that any way to analyze further ?
6. Expected response - 1 out of 5 request wins:

   [image]
7. bad response 2:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember when I was using HyperTerminal for the last time and I am not sure will it show whitespace characters (if I remember there is such settings).

One of the things that I would try is to install serial port sniffer or some advanced terminal (like [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/)) and verify that there is no some junk in form of white space characters that are hidden in HyperTerminal.

Comment: Thanks Darko, for sharing your opinion.   But I've no doubt on hyperterminal.  I suspect my wifi module.  Is that anyway i could capture the wifi frames and check ?